# The History of conventional current

Tags: theory, history

I would like to ask why the first scientists choose the current flow from high voltage(High potential) to low voltage(Low potential) which we know that it's wrong.I had heard and read that they take a random decision for the flow of the current, and for our bad luck it was this flow wrong!!!.**However, it was this statement(random choice) the real reason or something else made them to decide/choose this flow for the current.**

Comment: That's probability for you.

Comment: Why downvotes? This is a good question, One could think current is the direction of holes, but when we try to imagine what would be the mass of a hole, we go to the conclusion holes must be negative mass antimatter which can't cohabit with electrons, from a physics standpoint. Hence we live with an early assumption which was later proved to be wrong and unfixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electrons are not the only things that carry current. Holes do in semiconductors. Positive ions do in electrolytes. Why pick electrons over any other carrier?

The random decision doesn't matter. When we deal with conventional current, so the world of power supplies, meters, diodes, we don't worry about electrons or holes.

If we're doing something where we do care about the physics of carriers, we concentrate on those, see what sign they have, and use that sign when figuring out which way they're going to go in an electric field.

Comment: Neil_UK thanks for your answer.But I would like to understand how the first scientists decided this flow for the current.And why all scientists followed this convention and and no one disagreed?

Comment: What would you say of the mass of a hole? Ion flow exists ([mass spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry)), but hole is imaginary (hence conventional current is also imaginary), just a coordinated flow of electrons in the other direction (what is called a [quasiparticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle)). If holes existed, they would have a [negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) like [positrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron), but they couldn't be positrons, else they would produce gamma rays when encountering electrons.

Answer (score 4):

It goes back further than that really. They discovered we have positive and electric charges long before they discovered protons and electrons. For whatever reason made sense, probably due to the reaction of whatever device they detected the charge with, they called one positive and the other negative. They theorized discovered that "current" flows from the positive to the negative without actually knowing what was carrying the charge. They even theorized charge was a fluid.

> Benjamin Franklin proposed that electricity was not from different types of electrical fluid, but a single electrical fluid showing an excess (+) or deficit (-). He gave them the modern charge nomenclature of positive and negative respectively. Franklin thought of the charge carrier as being positive, but he did not correctly identify which situation was a surplus of the charge carrier, and which situation was a deficit. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron)

It was not till later in history that atoms, ions and electrons were actually discovered and the charges on those were identified. It turned out the electrons ended up being the majority carriers and were unfortunately negative by the measurements already in use.

As with most things in history, no one man or discovery defines everything. Rather one discovery is made and others build on that. When a "murphy's choice" is involved in there, it tends to get stuck at the foundation level and we live with it forever.

Had it been otherwise, everything we know would have been reversed. Schematically everything would look the same, but the electrons would flow in the same direction as the "current".

Comment: `C. F. du Fay, who proposed in 1733[1] that electricity comes in two varieties that cancel each other, and expressed this in terms of a two-fluid theory. When glass was rubbed with silk, du Fay said that the glass was charged with vitreous electricity, and, when amber was rubbed with fur, the amber was charged with resinous electricity.`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge

Comment: @user3528438 indeed, and that was before atoms were "discovered", let alone electrons.

Comment: Reading a couple biographies of Ben Franklin, he gets the credit for the Positive and the Negative labels. His scientific status was enormous, particularly in Europe. He exploited that status in arranging for loans from the close-to-broke French empire to fund American's revolution. Who can argue with the nomenclature used by an American icon in Paris?